# Onclick image change the input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Really stuck with this concept. IN my Old code have  separate input fields for `%`  input fields and `$`  input fields. its Working.

**Old UI code :**

```
 <td>Estimate Property Tax</td>
        <td>
          <input name="propertytaxpc" type="text" size="8" maxlength="8" value="<?php echo $dproperty_tax; ?>" onChange="javascript:propertyTaxPcChanged(true)" />
        %</td>
        <td>Or $ 

          <input name="propertytaxamt" type="text" size="8" maxlength="8" onChange="javascript:propertyTaxAmountChanged(true)"  />
          </td>
```

OLD UI i have used two  separate  input fields for `%` and `$`. its Working.  Now i changed NEW UI code

using Single Input Fields

**NEW UI CODE:**

```
<div class="col-md-4 padding-rht bdy">
     <label id="lblEstimatePropertyTax"class="pull-left"style="font-weight: 600">
     Estimate Property Tax</label>
     </div>

<div class="col-md-3 padding-rht">
   <input name="propertytaxpc" class="txt" type="text" size="8" maxlength="8" value="<?php echo $dproperty_tax;?>" onChange="javascript:propertyTaxPcChanged(true)" />


          </div>

  <div class="col-md-1 padding-lft">
   <img src="Content/Images/percent.png" onclick="changeColor(event,this.src)" style="cursor:pointer"/>
          </div>
```

> In My UI I'm Using IMAGE ICON FOR `%` AND `$` . In My Previous Code I AM
>   Using Each Input Fields for `%` and`$`. Now i'm  Using new UI using `%` AND
>   `$` Image .when user change `%` to `$` Image Icon values also changes.

i have tired many method really stuck with concept 
 already created ICON change script:

```
 function changeColor(event, _src) {
        var fname = _src;
        var ImageName = fname.substring(fname.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        //alert(ImageName);
        if (ImageName == "percent.png") {
            $(event.target).attr("src", "Content/Images/RedDoller.png");
        }
        else {
            $(event.target).attr("src", "Content/Images/percent.png");
       }
    }
```

Now i want pass value for Onclick image change ? when user change image value need to change.
 please help me any body really i am stuck with this concept ? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

**Js Change Image**

```
<img id="myImage" onclick="changeImage()" src="D:\\Images\\Img1.jpg" width="100" height="100">
<p id="myImageText">10</p>
</image>
```

*script*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeImage() {
    var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
    var txt = document.getElementById('myImageText');
    if (image.src.match("Img1")) {
        image.src = "D:\\Images\\Img2.jpg";
        txt.innerHTML = '20';
    } else {
        image.src = "D:\\Images\\Img1.jpg";
        txt.innerHTML = 10;
    }
}
</script>
```

*place all script tag data at the end so that the page loads fast.*

Comment: yash i need to pass value   already image change script Working Yash. i want pass two value single input fields . that value change when user change image

Comment: @RajVelN Hi, have you already find a solution on this scenario ?